# Can we authenticate facebook user which view page in UIWebView?

Tags: objective-c, facebook

I work on application which provide bonus content for certain actions Facebook Share, Facebook Like of our page and etc.

I have problem with Facebook Like, as we know Facebook SDK ToS don't allow us (developers) to programmatically like Facebook page, so I have two ideas

1. Open the native Facebook APP, which is straight forward.
2. UIWebView within' our APP. ***But here is the problem***

***How to authenticate the user in facebook, to skip the inconvenience of double login. (The first time is within' our app, to be able to fetch the result of `/me/likes/(id)`)?***

Comment: Facebook now don't allow to give permission @"publish_action". You cannot like page through graph API.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same problem for liking pages 
i found this
   https://github.com/brow/FacebookLikeView it is very help full go through this it shows how to like face book pages by using web view

hope this helps